# Restrict state change for predecessor successor work items

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

On Azure DevOps, I created a successor link between two work items. Now I want to restrict the state change of successor before predecessor state is completed.

Right now, all state changes are possible. How to restrict?

Comment: Hi, If this answer is helpful, would you please accept it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot restrict state change for predecessor successor work items now. I found a [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/prohibit-the-closing-of-a-successor-task-if-the-pr/365858) and we could follow this ticket to get the latest news.

In addition, You could add your request for this feature on the [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21%C2%A0), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.